# Docker container log retention

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We are running [Century Link's Watchtower](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower) container. This allows us to have a watch a docker registry and download new images when they are created. When watchtower finds a new image it runs `docker rmi` which deletes the old container. With that the old logs go with it.

Is there a way without using a logging service to retain the logs when docker does it's clean up?

Comment: Why are you averse to using a centralized logging service? It's something you should be doing anyway.

Comment: Has to do with our clients requiring them to open up outgoing ports. Ideally we would have an external system, trust me

Answer (score 2):

You've written "docker rmi" but I guess you meant "docker rm ..." as ***rm*** is for removing containers and ***rmi*** is for images(unless you are using --cleanup option to remove images).

You just have to give the -v parameter to your docker run command as in:

`$ docker run -d -P -v /log_directory docker_image ...`

and also you need to direct your logs to that docker volume(log_directory). By this way your log_directory will be permanent even if container is removed

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/